# Relative entropy between discrete and continuous random variables

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

Is this possible to define relative entropy between discrete and continuous random variables? Say $P$ is a discrete pmf and $Q$ is a continuous pdf, what is
$D(P||Q)$?

Answer (score 0):

An heuristic: let $P(x)$ be a train of $n$ thin rectangles over points $x_i$ $i=1 \cdots n$, with widths $\delta$ and heights $p_i /\delta$
Then, assuming $Q(x)$ is smooth and positive over the points $x_i$ :
$$ D(P||Q)=\int P(x) \log \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx \approx \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log \frac{p_i}{ \delta Q(x_i)}=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log \frac{p_i}{Q(x_i)} - \log{\delta}  $$
which tends to $+\infty$ as $\delta \to 0$. 
(Alternatively, we could also think of Q as a discrete variable with many values.)

Comment: Assume $P(x)$ is quantization of $Q(x)$. With your reasoning when $\delta\to 0$,  $D(P\|Q)\approx \infty$, but shouldn't it become $0$?

Comment: Why do you think it should become 0?

Comment: because the distributions become very close.